# how does socket.io work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io and it was quick to setup (thanks to examples on their usage page) but i'd like to find out more about what exactly is going on under covers and what's the technology that makes it work.

what are the exact mechanics of socket.io?

is it on port 80 or a separate one?

does it really stay open or is that part simulated?

is there a way to profile each socket event ? 
(sort of like using fiddler to see what happens in ajax calls)

Comment: eh? my questions are pretty specific.

Comment: Well, some are quite broad ("what are the exact mechanics"?), also, multiple questions in one are usually not a good idea. Try reading the docs on http://socket.io/docs/ , and on https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io (socket.io uses Engine.io). Then ask a more focused question.

Comment: Even after reading the docs on socket.io's website, it's not clear how it works internally.

Comment: agreed there, SO should automatically open these posts after a certain amount of upvotes.

Comment: @SonicSoul voted for reopen

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For debugging, you might want to try out [**Theseus**](https://github.com/adobe-research/theseus).

Here is a short overview of the [**socket.io SPEC**](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec):

> Socket.IO aims to bring a WebSocket-like API to many browsers and
>   devices, with some specific features to help with the creation of
>   real-world realtime applications and games.
>
> - Multiple transport support (old user agents, mobile browsers, etc).
> - Multiple sockets under the same connection (namespaces).
> - Disconnection detection through heartbeats.
> - Optional acknoledgments.
> - Reconnection support with buffering (ideal for mobile devices or bad networks)
> - Lightweight protocol that sits on top of HTTP.
>
> #### Anatomy of a Socket.IO socket
>
> A Socket.IO client first decides on a transport to utilize to connect.
>
> The state of the Socket.IO socket can be `disconnected`,
>   `disconnecting`, `connected` and `connecting`.
>
> The transport connection can be `closed`, `closing`, `open`, and
>   `opening`.
>
> A simple HTTP handshake takes place at the beginning of a Socket.IO
>   connection. The handshake, if successful, results in the client
>   receiving:
>
> - A session id that will be given for the transport to open connections.
> - A number of seconds within which a heartbeat is expected (`heartbeat timeout`)
> - A number of seconds after the transport connection is closed when the socket is considered disconnected if the transport connection is
>     not reopened (`close timeout`).
>
> At this point the socket is considered connected, and the transport is
>   signaled to open the connection.
>
> If the transport connection is closed, both ends are to buffer
>   messages and then frame them appropriately for them to be sent as a
>   batch when the connection resumes.
>
> If the connection is not resumed within the negotiated timeout the
>   socket is considered disconnected. At this point the client might
>   decide to reconnect the socket, which implies a new handshake.

If you need more of the details, you can read the rest of the specification [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec)

Comment: this is great! thanks @JAM. appreciate it

Comment: HTTP handshake?

Answer (score 36):

JAM's post does a good job of summarizing what socket.io *is*; I'd like to specifically address some of your other questions.

- Socket.io attaches to an instance of `http.Server` and adds handlers to it.  It does not listen to a network port on its own; it simply adds socket.io-specific handlers to an existing HTTP server.  (However, if you call `io.listen()` with a number, it internally creates a new HTTP server that listens to the specified port and attaches to that.)
- It really stays open if it is using the [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) transport.  It also includes fallback mechanisims that use traditional (long-)polling ajax requests.  So the answer depends on what APIs the browser supports.  (You can optionally configure which fallbacks you'd like to use, if any.)
- Fiddler supports websockets now, as does Chrome's developer tools:

[image]