# Similarity/Difference between SocketIO and EventEmitter in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, eventemitter, socket.io

I am little confuse between Socket.io and EventEmitter API in nodejs. Yes, I am quite new in event driven NodeJS programming. Is there any significant difference between this two ? or one have made over the other one ? are they designed to serve the same purpose or different ?
Any example/resource link, illustrating difference between them would be nice..

Comment: Read more about asynchronous programming, `socket.io` uses `EventEmitter` for events `connection`,`disconnect`, etc.. don't compare class against package ..

Comment: it mixes streams with events, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719282/how-does-socket-io-work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You shouldn't compare the `EventEmitter` API and Socket.IO, as they are completely different things and are unrelated except for the fact that Socket.IO uses events, both on the server side and client side.

The `EventEmitter` API is used by anything that emits events, for example, a HTTP server, streams, file operations, etc. They are used like this:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
// create a new instance
var em = new EventEmitter();

// attach a handler to an event named "event"
em.on('event', function() {
});

// fire the "event" event
em.emit('event');
```

Socket.IO on the other hand, is a library for cross-browser realtime data transport. It is used to send data from a client to a server, or from a server to a client.

```
// on the server side
var io = require('socket.io');
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('event');
});

// on the client side
var socket = io.connect();
socket.emit('data');
```

Comment: Thanks buddy... as any doubt is always a doubt without sound knowledge.. I will get hands on over both. Can you suggest some good book or resource for socket.io, I need some more knowledge about it.

Comment: The documentation is the best place to look, as well as the [wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki) on their Github.

Comment: Can we use EventEmitter to emit events from a Service (Microservice Architecture) and listen to that event from another Service using Socket.io?

Comment: Answering the question of Dheeraj Kumar, as far as I understand it is not possible to use the EventEmitter between different services, since it is designed for component interaction, meaning that it will only work internally.

Comment: @DheerajKumar I am able to get it working across services via EventSource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource

Comment: In the browser it is included but for nodejs you have to explicitly install it