# Websocket connection. Why are we making a call to ws://echo.websocket.org?

Tags: websocket

I am writing some websocket code and I have this so far:

```
window.onload = function() {

  // Get references to elements on the page.
  var form = document.getElementById('message-form');
  var messageField = document.getElementById('message');
  var messagesList = document.getElementById('messages');
  var socketStatus = document.getElementById('status');
  var closeBtn = document.getElementById('close');

  var socket = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');

  // Show a connected message when the WebSocket is opened.
  socket.onopen = function(event) {
    socketStatus.innerHTML = 'Connected to: ' + event.currentTarget.url;
    socketStatus.className = 'open';
  };

  // Handle any errors that occur.
  socket.onerror =  function(error) {
    console.log('WebSocket Error: ' + error);
  };

  form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Retrieve the message from the textarea.
    var message = messageField.value;

    // Send the message through the WebSocket.
    socket.send(message);

    // Add the message to the messages list.
    messagesList.innerHTML += '<li class="sent"><span>Sent:</span>' + message +
                              '</li>';

    // Clear out the message field.
    messageField.value = '';

    return false;
  };

  socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    var message = event.data;
    messagesList.innerHTML += '<li class="received"><span>Received:</span>' +
                             message + '</li>';
  };

  closeBtn.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Close the WebSocket.
    socket.close();

    return false;
  };

  socket.onclose = function(event) {
    socketStatus.innerHTML = 'Disconnected from WebSocket.';
    socketStatus.className = 'closed';
  };
};
```

What is this code doing:

```
 var socket = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');
```

What url is that? When I visit there with my browser it does not exist but it seems to be important as I can't simply jus replace that url with random strings. What does it do? Is Websocket an external API?

I'm looking at the network tab and I see this:

```
Request URL: ws://echo.websocket.org/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
```

conceptually, what is going on? Why do I need to make a request to an external site to use Websockets?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`echo.websocket.org` provides a webSocket server that lets you make a webSocket connection to it and then it simply echos back to you anything that you send it.  It's there primarily for testing and demo purposes.

The code you show looks like a demo/testing app designed to run in a browser web page for a webSocket connection which you can access something similar here: https://websocket.org/echo.html.

A URL starting with `ws://` indicates a connection that intends to use the webSocket protocol.

> What is this code doing:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');
```

It is making a webSocket connection to a webSocket server at `echo.websocket.org`.

> What url is that?

That is a webSocket URL that indicates the intent to use the webSocket protocol to connect and talk to that host.  This is not something you type in the URL bar of a browser.  It's something that is used by a programming language (such as Javascript in your browser).

> Is Websocket an external API?

It's a protocol that specifies a means of connecting, a security scheme, a packet data format, etc...  You could say that the http protocol is to the webSocket protocol as the English language is to Japanese.  They are different means of communicating.  The specification for the webSocket protocol is here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455.

It's also designed to fit well into the http/browser world and to be friendly with infrastructure that was originally designed for http requests.  Just searching for "what is websocket" on Google will turn up all sorts of descriptive articles.  The [Wikipedia page for webSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) provides a pretty good overview.

There is tons written on the web about what the webSocket protocol is and is useful for so I won't repeat that here.  You can see a tutorial on webSocket clients [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) and a tutorial on webSocket servers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers).

In a nutshell, it's designed to be a long lasting, continuous connection (supported in all modern browsers) that allows a client to connect to a server and then maintain a continuous connection for (potentially) a long duration.  While that connection is open, data can be easily sent both ways over the webSocket.  The primary reason people use it is when they want the server to be able to send data directly to the client in a timely fashion without making the client continuously ask the server over and over again if it has any new data.  Once a webSocket connection is established, the server can just "push" data to the client at any time.

> I'm looking at the network tab and I see this.  Conceptually, what is going on?
>
> Request URL: ws://echo.websocket.org/
>
> Request Method: GET Status Code:
>
> 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake

Those are the first steps of establishing a webSocket connection.  You can see a more complete description of how that connection works here: [How socket.io works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309640/how-socket-io-works/38311227#38311227).  That post talks about socket.io which is another layer built on top of webSocket, but the underlying protocol is webSocket.

> Why do I need to make a request to an external site to use Websockets?

A webSocket's purpose is to connect a client to a server (so data can then be sent between them) so it would only be used when connecting to some server somewhere.