# Why my node.js webserver is receiving several requests from browser?

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, browser, webserver

Hy, im making a simple http server with sockets from node.js native net module that run on "localhost:4000" and gives only "hello, world!" webpage.

The server is running OK and on my server i make some debugs with console.log() menssages: "listening connections", "client connected", "received data" and "sending data".

My problem is when i go on browser and open the webpage im getting 3 connections: 1- "GET / HTTP/1.1" 2- "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" and the third connection dont request anything only connects to server.

Here is my webserver code:

```js
const net = require('net') //import net module
const ip = "localhost"; //ip of connection
const port = 4000; //port of connection

const response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"+
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n"+
"Content-Encoding: UTF-8\n"+
"Accept-Ranges: bytes\n"+
"Connection: keep-alive\n\n"+
"<h1>Hello, world!</h1>"; //"webpage" http response 

const server = net.createServer(); //create server
server.listen(port, ip); //starts server

server.on("listening", () => {
    console.log("-Listening connections");
}); //event called on servers starts listening for connections

server.on("connection", handleConnection); //event called when the client has connected

function handleConnection(socket){ //this callback runs when client connects
    console.log("("+socket.remoteAddress+":"+socket.remotePort+") connected");

    socket.on("data", (data) => { //event called when client send data to server
        console.log("-received data from: "+socket.remoteAddress+":"+socket.remotePort);
        console.log(data.toString());
        socket.write(response, () => { //sends the response (webpage) to client
            console.log("-sending response: "+socket.remoteAddress+":"+socket.remotePort)
            socket.end(); //close client connection
        });
    });

    socket.on("close", () => { //event called when client connection has closed
        console.log("-socket close");
    });
}
```

And this is the console.log messages when browser connects:

```
-Listening connections
(127.0.0.1:57306) connected
-received data from: 127.0.0.1:57306
-sending response: 127.0.0.1:57306  
-socket close
(127.0.0.1:57308) connected
-received data from: 127.0.0.1:57308
-sending response: 127.0.0.1:57308  
-socket close
(127.0.0.1:57309) connected
```

server remains listening (because it only close after receiving a request) but without more requests and if i refresh the page, the connection seems to be continuing where it left off, reusing the last socket conection alive before.
Back to console.log message above were has finishied on *"(127.0.0.1:57309) connected"*, after refresh, the browser connects to the socket that was aliving and the log messages are:

```
...
...(same msg above)
...
-received data from: 127.0.0.1:57608
-sending response: 127.0.0.1:57608
-socket close
...
...(and keeping this loop every page refresh, like reusing las socket openned)
...
```

Lastly... how to handle this browser requests? I just want to response the "webpage get request" and nothing more. Why browser resquest 3 requisitions?

Comment: Did you tried use the socket.io? Here is a little explanation about it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719282/how-does-socket-io-work

Comment: yeah, socket.io and builtin http module. boths works fine
but my objectives is make this using a low level api cause i have to use this in the future. Socket.io and http module are abstractions of net sockets/streams and now im searching for how it's are implemented.

I discovered this article who will reviews the structure of http requests and responses and get an introduction to node's stream api.

https://www.codementor.io/@ziad-saab/let-s-code-a-web-server-from-scratch-with-nodejs-streams-h4uc9utji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, several years have passed, and if I run the same code now, this strange behavior no longer appears.

Also, while reading my code now, it seems that the behavior occurs because I only call `socket.end(); //close client connection` when the request has data. (The socket.end() is called inside the socket.on('data') event.) If I try to connect to my server without sending any data, then this behavior occurs.

It seems that the browser or another client that I used at that time (I don't remember) appears to establish that blank connection without any data.

The solution is simple: call `socket.end()` outside the `socket.on('data')` event.